# Moving sqlite3 file to new server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have read over the main pages at http://www.sqlite.org.  Is it correct to say I can simply upload the sqlite3 file given to me for a new RoR site (Refinery CMS) and it will be available?  I can't seem to find any information about permissions or any procedures for "installing" the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sqlite file *is* the database, so you should be able to copy it to another server/location without trouble.

If your application's `config/database.yml` file is configured *(for the environment the server is configured for)* to point to the database's path and the application user can read the file based on it's permissions, nothing more should have to be done.

Comment: Thank you!  This is how I was understanding the docs but they didn't quite address my situation.